# Media ContentObserver not raising onChange events

Tags: java, android, contentobserver

I'm attempting to get my Android application to open up the camera application and allow the user to take a series of photos, then upon exiting, I want to use a `ContentObserver` to query `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to find the pictures that the user took.

The problem, however, is that `PhotoObserver.onChange` is never being called even after taking a series of photos and hitting the back button.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    PhotoObserver photoObserver = new PhotoObserver(new Handler());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, false, photoObserver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        this.getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .unregisterContentObserver(photoObserver);
    }

    // Called when a button is hit!
    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
        startActivity(cameraIntent);
    }

    public class PhotoObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public PhotoObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            onChange(selfChange, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
            super.onChange(selfChange, uri);

            // This never gets called!
            System.out.println("onChange called");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know, taking photos by default camera activity doesn't necessarily store them in gallery, so your observer is not triggered.

Comment: @Arkadiy It definitely stores them in the gallery.

Comment: @Colin, Did you find solution?